# Android SDK missing with Android Studio 3

Tags: android, sdk, installation, android-studio-3.0

I've just downloaded **Android Studio 3** for Windows from the [official website](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html), but when it starts, it displays an error message about a **missing Android SDK**:

[image: Android SDK missing. You can obtain it from d.android.com/sdk]

When I click that link, it just redirects to the same official website. There isn't a separate link there for SDK download.

Where could I get it from? Shouldn't the Android SDK be installed during Android Studio 3 setup?

Comment: Why not to download sdk seprately and give path there

Comment: It nay happened after install new version and not import setting from previous version . but what happen if select `SDK`(path) manually?

Comment: @Akashkumar - That's exactly what I'd like to do. But I don't know how to download the SDK separately.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html  see in last of page  or search page with " sdk-tools-windows-3859397.zip " or download the studio and install the SDK it will be created in another folder

Comment: @Akashkumar: initially followed these steps but that didn't work.  It only installs the **tools** directory and AS was still complaining about the missing SDK stuff.  The only solution forward is the one given by AttilaTanyi below.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was that Android Studio 3.0 had already been installed and uninstalled before this. The SDK got removed, but Android Studio's config didn't.

**Removing the config from a previous install** (`C:\Users\<user>\.AndroidStudio3.0` folder) did the trick. When Android Studio started up, it opened a dialog about which parts of the SDK to download, and then proceeded as expected.

Comment: BEWARE: this causes a fresh download of all components which is quite time-consuming. It did not fix my problem.

Comment: It took me a whole day to figure that one out. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This happened with me on **Windows 10** with **Android Studio 3.1**.  The **SDK was missing** & **I couldn't download or install it** with the IDE.  Android Studio wasn't downloading or installing the SDK properly, despite going through the steps.  An **error** would appear at the end of the SDK configuration wizard telling me the SDK hadn't been installed b/c the sdk/tools directory didn't exist (*no sh1t sherlock*).  I had *not* previously downloaded or installed Android Studio or the SDK.

It turns out that Android Studio 3.1 didn't have option checked for **'Enable embedded Maven repository'** in the **IDE Preferences**.

After **enabling** the **embedded Maven repo** & restarting Android Studio, the **SDK** configuration wizard started up & **successfully downloaded/installed** the SDK.

Comment: rats. after a thorough search my copy of Android Studio doesn't have a IDE Preferences menu.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple:

- Select `SDK Manager` from the `Tools` menu in Android Studio.
  It will open a window called "Settings for New Projects".
  [image]
- Click on `Android SDK` then select the Android SDK you want to download.
  [image]

This will definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

try to reinstall it and download(automatically downloaded) the required file after restart, but follow the steps

1 go to your main drive(consider 'c') then c/user//androidstudioproject and copy it to some other location(save your old 
    projects to safe location)

2 uninstall android studio from control panel

3 delete following file

```
    a c/user/<your system name>/androidstudioproject

    b c/user/<your system name>/.android

  c 'c/user/<your system name>/AppData/Local/Android (keep hidden files on)'
```

4 now install your androidstudio from its setup

these will automatically download the required files after installation (always connect to internet while installing)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! These steps didn't solve the problem, but helped moving in the right direction. Removing the config from a previous install (`Users/<user>/.AndroidStudio3.0` folder) did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled Android Studio from Control Pannel. 
Save in a safe place the folder and subfolders below `C:\USERS\MYNAME\ANDROIDSTUDIOPROJECTS`

After I deleted `c:\users\MYNAME\.ANDROIDSTUDIO3.1` AND `c:\users\MYNAME\.ANDROID`

After all I installed android studio.
Take a long time but it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on MacOS, the Android Studio installer puts the bundled SDK files into `~/Library/Android/sdk/`

Answer (score 1):

by thanks from @Harsh.jaiswal

**just delete this files:**

```
 1. c/user/<your system name>/androidstudioproject
 2. c/user/<your system name>/.android
 3. c/user/<your system name>/AppData/Local/Android (keep hidden files on)
```

**So AS will automatically download the required files**

Answer (score 0):

You can download sdk tools separately.
https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads

Go to this link and download the sdk tools from under "Command line tools only".
after download, extract the zip file and move it to C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

If not worked, change sdk location from android studio

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and after uninstall and reinstall, still could not find the option under Tools.

After I opened a project, I found the option. There is a button (fourth from the right) that is the SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually create
`C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

and then I downloaded the tools from `Command Line Tools Only` section on: https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads

then I extracted the files to:
`C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

Hope this helps someone.