# Android SDK not found after Installation of new Android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I installed the new version of Android Studio 3.0.(Which contains only IDE not SDK) in windows 10. When the installation completed, it showed "No Android SDK Found". When I try to setup sdk from SDK manager, all tabs are disabled. Can't able to select SDK tools. If I edit the android location and try to setup sdk component then at the end I get

**Nothing to do!
SDK tools directory is missing**

I tried with many solutions provided by stackoverflow threads. I even tried to install sdk separately but all the download urls are redirect to Android studio download page which of course doesn't have a sdk.  Where do I get the SDK separately ?

What could be gone wrong during setup/installation?

Comment: Did you installed in past? May be this help you:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633035/no-android-sdk-found-android-studio , https://stackoverflow.com/a/46965692/3974530

Comment: I had studio. But i re-image my PC and trying to install all the software again. And I am stuck at this Android studio setup.

Comment: Downlaod from here:- https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Answer (score -2):

I think you should completely remove the studio(including cache files and previous setting). Try reinstalling again

Comment: I did that. Same problem again. :(