# Android SDK missing with Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android-studio, sdk

This question is closed to another question:[Android SDK missing with Android Studio 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962775/android-sdk-missing-with-android-studio-3)

I followed all the recommandation already proposed but I still have the issue.

I had some issues when I tried to update my Android Stduio to version 3.1.
Thus, I uninstalled everything, then delete the directories, and cleaned C:\Users\.android, .AndroidStudio, ..

But I always have the same message at the end, indicating that SDK tools directory is missing.

[SDK tools directory is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo8w2.png)

And if I enter SDK Components Setup, I have the following window. I cannot click in the Android SDK box (insidcating already installed ?), and at the end the same message than above.

[SDK Components Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xJD8.png)

I already spent a full day on this issue and I cannot find the solution. I would really appreciate some help !
I work on Windows 7 (64 bits version)

Comment: this helped me with the issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962775/android-sdk-missing-with-android-studio-3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SDK missing with Android Studio 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962775/android-sdk-missing-with-android-studio-3)

Answer (score 0):

On the top right corner, there is a the SDK Manager, click on it if the SDK path is not defined install a new one and then set its path to where it is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "install a new one". How to do it ? I didn't find any stand alone package. It seems that now, it can only be part of Android Studio installer.

Comment: no, i mean when you click there a menu of recent and old SDKs will appear such as android P, andoird oreo,... and so on. then install one of them oreo recommened

Comment: Ok I understand. In fact I do not see any propoal here, the SDK list is empty. It seems that I have a proxy setting issue that is the source of the problem. When I try to check for update, I have the message "Connection failed (Status:407). Please check network connection and try again". However, In the HTTP proxy settings  window, everything is correctly set, and it works when I check the connection.

Comment: As written in the comments above, seems that the issue came from proxy. For any reason, Andorid sudio could not access https. To be honnest, I do not know what was the issue, as the configuration was ok. I finally disable the proxy and recheck both HTTP and HTTPS connection before installing Android Studio. Now it seems ok.

Comment: @Jean-Marc How did you recheck the HTTP and HTTPS connection before installing Android Studio?